# Keyboard Shortcut for the Visual Studio Package Manager Console?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

What is the Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to open the Package Manager Console?

If one doesn't exist, then how can we create it?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

To open the Package Manager Console, hit the following four keys in succession without holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. This is not exactly a shortcut but works for me.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Nice. I like the built in shortcut.

Comment: For me (VS2013 and VS2015) it's a different combination, not sure why: `Alt V E O`

Comment: @NelsonReis and you have VS installed in english?

Comment: @SergeAdneom I do, but I don't have that machine anymore, so I've went to test on my current machine and both of the key successions work, because Package Manager Console is available on both menus `"View > Other windows > PMC"` and `"Tools > NuGet Package Manager > PMC"`.

Comment: Well, here what you are doing is just to select shortcuts of the menu items. As you now, when you hit Alt, you activate the main menu by highlighting one character in each main menu title. select one of the characters and then the menu below it will open, and so on so forth. In this case, Alt T N O simply opens the Tools menu, then it selects NuGet Package Manager submenu, followed by Package Manage Console item. You figure out what Alt V E O does

Comment: It works, but on mine (2017), I closed the PMC accidentally and the options for the console were grayed out.  I closed and reopened and could use the combination.

Comment: VS2019 - Can select Visual Studio Code mapping scheme: CTRL-` and then `CTRL-TAB` to get swap back.

Answer (score 59):

You can set one by going to the "TOOLS" menu and choosing "OPTIONS" then then choosing the "Environment -> Keyboard" section.

Then choose the "View.PackageManagerConsole" option from the list box.  You type in the search box above the list box to filter it.  Then you can set your shortcut key.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301962%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) helped me work out the details.

Comment: Sweet, now I can just use CTRL-P. What that shortcut used to do wasn't particularly helpful - I have never once needed to print my code!

Comment: I have assigned CTRL+ALT+P, CTRL+ALT+M and it works great

Comment: Great, set it to ctrl + ` to match VS Code. Now if only it toggled it instead of just launching it...

Comment: @MattWest Me, too, but at least `CTRL-TAB` gets you back to the last window.

Answer (score 8):

Use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>

As path for `View` → `Other windows` → `Package Manager Console`

Comment: That's a language specific shortcut and does not work in every VS Installation

Comment: @boop what do you mean by language specific? And wich VS installation it does not work with?

Comment: ALT+V is for View. It's another shortcut in other languages. Like ALT+A for Ansicht

Comment: @boop Its not ALT+V only its Alt + V + E + O, also i cannot see any conflict this shortcut is inside Visual Studio

Comment: It is ALT+v to open view, then E then O to trigger following actions.

Comment: @boop Yes it will

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd> works for me in VS 16.7.5.